# Order dates inside a string from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, calendar

I have this kind of list of lists I give you example input:

```
thislist= [[1, 'Aug 2014, Sept 2016, Ian 2014, Feb 2016', 2], [5,'Aug 2015, Sept 2012, Ian 2015, Aug 2017',4]]
```

I'm interested to work only at index[1] for each list (the one with the dates) and my desired output will be this:

```
thislist= [[1, 'Ian, Aug 2014; Feb, Sept 2016', 2], [5,'Sept 2012; Ian, Aug 2015; Aug 2017',4]]
```

(the above it's just a example, in my actual case I will have many more dates with years, but the format is exactly the same)
Basically I want to order each dates name abbreviation (they are in Romanian but they are quite same in English) on their actual order from calendar (ex: Ian, Feb, Mar, Apr ...etc) and to have them grouped like in the example on years in cronological order (2010, 2011, 2012, 2013 ....etc) and have that ";" for separation. How I can do this? I think the only option should be regex, but I'm not that good with it, so I can get to my desired output? I'm using python 3, thank you so much for your time!

Comment: The tools to use are a translate function, `split()`, `sort()` and `join()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take consider that "%B %Y" it takes full month Name because Romanian and English month abbreviation is not same in all cases

```
from datetime import datetime
thislist = [[1, 'August 2014, September 2016, January 2014, February 2016', 2],
            [5, 'August 2015, September 2012, January 2015, February 2017', 4]]
sorted_list = []
months = []
i = 0
for dates in thislist:
    sorted_list = []
    chgDates = dates[1].split(",")
    for test1 in chgDates:
        sorted_list.append(test1.strip())
    test = sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%B %Y"))
    str1 = ', '.join(test)
    thislist[i][1] = str1.replace(",", ";")
    i = + 1

print(thislist)
```

Response:

```
[[1, 'January 2014; August 2014; February 2016; September 2016', 2], [5, 'September 2012; January 2015; August 2015; February 2017', 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you Cristian, I can't create a map for the sorting ? I mean to map the names in English with the ones in Romanians in order to sort them in Romanian?

Comment: And also I don't need after each month the year (check my example for the desired output, 'January 2014; August 2014; February 2016; September 2016' should be 'January, August 2014; February, September 2016'

Answer (score 0):

Now you can translate from English-> Romanian. You should read a little bit about lists and dictionary in python. I don't think that you will receive a full answer if you just wait for community.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
thislist = [[1, 'August 2014, September 2016, January 2014, February 2016, March 2016', 2],
            [5, 'August 2015, September 2012, January 2015, February 2017', 4]]
sorted_list = []
months = []
i = 0


def translateInRo(string, dyct):
    substrs = sorted(dyct, key=len, reverse=True)

    regexp = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, substrs)))

    return regexp.sub(lambda match: dyct[match.group(0)], string)


for dates in thislist:
    sorted_list = []
    chgDates = dates[1].split(",")
    for test1 in chgDates:
        sorted_list.append(test1.strip())
    test = sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%B %Y"))
    str1 = ', '.join(test)
    translate = translateInRo(
        str1, {"September": "Septembrie", "January": "Ianuarie", "September": "Septembrie", "February": "Februarie", "March": "Martie"})
    thislist[i][1] = translate
    i = + 1

print(thislist)
```

Comment: This looks almost perfect, it's there a way to remove the year and only let the last entry year from this 'Ianuarie 2014, August 2014, Februarie 2016, Martie 2016, Septembrie 2016', 2] to this ['Ianuarie, August 2014, Februarie, Martie, Septembrie 2016', 2], maybe with some regex ?